# SQL multiple select rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, multiple-select-query

```
Name | Status      | value
-----+-------------+-------
wec1 | rotortemp   | Null
wec1 | baldetemp   | Null
wec1 | Cabinettemp | 1
wec2 | rotortemp   | Null
wec2 | baldetemp   | Null
wec2 | Cabinettemp | Null
```

How can I select all the wec1 because the value of one row of wec1 is = 1

Comment: So what have you tried, and what's not working about it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no evidence the OP has tried anything to deal with this themselves

Comment: Well I have searched for it. But when you do not have the correct keywords, sometimes will fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name
               FROM TableName
               WHERE value=1)
```

Comment: perfect thats working

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but maybe something like:

```
SELECT      Name,
            Status,
            value

FROM        yourtable

WHERE       Name IN (
    SELECT      Name
    FROM        yourtable
    WHERE       value = 1
)
```